# disable foreign key constraint trigger in one transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I am trying to make a delete call that triggers a recursive foreign key (which doesn't have an index). The query is very slow.

I've been searching for a while and it seems my options are

1. add index on fk -- this is not ideal because the write speed for this table is very important, and already not very good
2. disable trigger for session -- again not ideal because it's exposed to other transactions, would prefer this only applies to an isolated transaction where others are not affected
3. extend trigger --- this one i'm curious about. Is it possible to store a local variable with `set_config` which we then check against i.e if var=== true run trigger else don't? Something like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62010745/7530306

Comment: Look at deferred constraints

Comment: I have, they don't improve the performance time from what i could tell. It is hard to judge as I can't see how long the constraint takes at commit time

Answer (score 1):

You can change the parameter `session_replication_role` to `replica`, then only replica triggers will fire, and foreign key constraints won't be checked. That requires superuser permissions, because it endangers the integrity of the database.

I don't see your point. If you disable the foreign key, why keep it around at all? If you are not ready to pay the price, do without referential integrity.

My advice is:

- If you need to delete rows frequently, create the index.  The risk of violating the constaint by repeatedly disabling it is too high.
- If this is a one-time affair, accept the sequential scan on the referencing table.

Comment: @sf8193, as Laurenz Albe stated you should create index. Generally, you should create index on foreign key column in order to faster retrieval and not to cause any lock on the table. Yet, you are suffering from long insert response. So, it just a trade off. By the way, what is your physical resources. You are using SSD?

Comment: @UmutTEKİN The index has no influence on locking (unless you use `SERIALIZABLE` isolation). It also does not speed up retrieval, unless you want a nested loop join between the tables.

Comment: could you please explain "It also does not speed up retrieval"? You mean in this particular case they do not speed up data retrieval?

Comment: @UmutTEKİN What I said was not quite accurate. Of course the index will speed up searches *on the referencing table* if you search for the foreign key. I was talking about searches *on the referenced table*, which is the one the question is about. Anyway, the question is about `DELETE`.

Comment: creating the index affects consumers of the application to a point that's probably unacceptable, unfortunately this isn't a one time affair. As far as disabling foreign key, it wouldn't be at all times just within when we need to delete.